# How to use addClass with .live change

Tags: jquery, live, addclass

I'm using jquery 1.6.1.When I want to use addClass with live change, it doesn't work.
please look at my example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/mr_seven/Mp8zc/1/

```
$("#qty").live('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == '1'){
        jQyery('#card_2').addClass('takhfif');
    } else {
        jQyery('#card_2').removeClass('takhfif');
    }
});
```

Comment: @moonwave99 Maybe he's using noConflict

Comment: @RGraham then he should not be using `$` one line above ^^ [outside the fact he is not using it, in the fiddle at least].

Comment: @moonwave99 Good point, didn't see the fiddle! Code is a mess anyway.

Comment: The incorrect spelling of jQuery could be a hint ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have typo for selector. it should be `jQuery` not `jQyery`:

```
$("#qty").live('change', function() {
 if ($(this).val() == '1'){
     jQuery('#card_2').addClass('takhfif');
  } else {
     jQuery('#card_2').removeClass('takhfif');
 }});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp8zc/5/)**

Comment: @Adil:Thanks adil...updated now.

Answer (score 0):

This should be `jQuery` not `jQyery`:

```
$("#qty").live('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '1'){
    jQuery('#card_2').addClass('takhfif');
  } else {
     jQuery('#card_2').removeClass('takhfif');
  }
});
```